# 20% faster with unused variable? Why?

Tags: python, performance, cpython, python-internals

I'm doing a lot of benchmarks. I've never seen something like this. I'm stumped. Creating an extra global variable, not used at all, makes part of my code about 20% faster. **Why?**

I'm benchmarking a function that produces iterables, measuring how long it takes to consume (iterate) them. I have two ways for consuming. Typical times when I get high CPU share:

```
       | Without the variable | With the variable 
-------+----------------------+-------------------
Output |   0.74 s  consume_1  |  0.72 s  consume_1 
       |   0.96 s  consume_2  |  0.77 s  consume_2 
       |                      |                    
       |   0.74 s  consume_1  |  0.75 s  consume_1 
       |   0.96 s  consume_2  |  0.78 s  consume_2 
       |                      |                    
       |   0.73 s  consume_1  |  0.73 s  consume_1 
       |   0.95 s  consume_2  |  0.78 s  consume_2 
-------+----------------------+-------------------
Debug  |  Real time: 5.110 s  | Real time: 4.560 s
       |  User time: 4.546 s  | User time: 4.386 s
       |  Sys. time: 0.535 s  | Sys. time: 0.150 s
       |  CPU share: 99.43 %  | CPU share: 99.47 %
```

Creating the pointless variable makes the consumption with `consume_2` about 0.2 seconds faster (from 0.97 to 0.77). Also, significant differences in the "Debug" statistics. The most drastic is "Sys. time": for "without" it's consistently around 0.5 seconds and for "with" it's consistently around 0.14 seconds.

I'm doing this on TIO, and you can reproduce it there yourself:
[Without the variable](https://tio.run/##dVLbbsMgDH3PV/ilKlmjKmlfpkj9hf1AVUU0cVokAgzcLf36DEIuWqfxBD7HPsc25kl3rY7vxg5Da3UHJDoUBKIz2tL0SkZEG7SctJ0xQdjdkAhtxP3bktbSzQSLBvmUXGspsSah1QI3@PnAJGmwBeT1vfoWdK803dG6qmChGr9KTMsE/OkdnIAeRuKKjEAbDGXQg1CA6tEFj8h6N@WF8xQoG@g9yZ1LcYFduIhdUV6SpPaGfFKV@/IfWk1@5mjBXp1NZYNqgDKI4VH9hboaGDtlMZpBnv4WOfwnEh@h8Y4bto6bFWn2Ry1OIyoF@nib7XnVuAyWp2l0IB35wlI4YparG7Ii9yf1SOjNafmFNnR1/rubC7zBcZ3D1EcgL3PL1u7WMQTB@KGY5N214eXMYlGPeVPBn1/jFe2pSJdUY4Uitt3sDy042MIGaJHYV5XiXqmK9EhNh@EH) / [With the variable](https://tio.run/##dVLbboMwDH3nK/xSNVlRBe3LhNRf2A9UFQpgSqRAWOJu9OtZQrhonZanxOfY59hO/6RGd@f33oxjbXQLJFuUBLLttaH5FU2I7tEI0mbBJGF7RyI0AXdvQ1oruxAM9ijm5FIrhSVJ3a1whZ8PjKIKa0BRNvm3pCbX1KCxecp8NVEo5FkE7gwWLkCPXuGGTEDtDcUwgOwAu0frPSIb7Jznz1OiqmBwJHvN5A0O/iIPaXaLotIZckl54sp/6G72s0RT9upsLutVPRRDCE/qL9TNwNQpC9EYEv5b5PSfSHj4xlvRs23cLOXxH7UwjaDk6dNtsedUwzJYwnlwoCy5wkpaYkZ0d2Rp4g7nUa11IcwyDt@o1eoLjW/x@ndRN3iD8zaUuSlPXocYb61uM/Hq4XcxJdqiEtnCYkGPOYferNtpgeaS8jW1N7Ijtt8dTzVY2MMOaJU45nknnFIe6IHKx/EH)

Here's the code, I called the extra variable `foobar`. Also note that `consume_1` loads the global `deque` 10000 times while `consume_2` has just a handful of loads of globals, so if anything, I'd think that `consume_1` would be the affected one.

```
from timeit import timeit
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import repeat
from collections import deque

def each_with_others_1(iterable):
    xs = tuple(iterable)
    for i, x in enumerate(xs):
        yield x, xs[:i] + xs[i+1:]

consume_0 = None

def consume_1(each_with_others):
    for each, others in each_with_others:
        deque(others, 0)

def consume_2(each_with_others):
    otherss = map(itemgetter(1), each_with_others)
    deque(map(deque, otherss, repeat(0)), 0)

lst = list(range(10000))
foobar = None
for solver in [each_with_others_1] * 3:
    for consume in consume_1, consume_2:
        t = timeit(lambda: consume(solver(lst)), number=1)
        print('%.2f s ' % t, consume.__name__)
    print()
```

Update: Also reproduced on a Google Compute Engine instance after installing Python 3.8.2, creating the variable made `consume_2` about 15% faster:

```
       | Without the variable | With the variable 
-------+----------------------+-------------------
Output |   0.64 s  consume_1  |  0.65 s  consume_1 
       |   0.80 s  consume_2  |  0.68 s  consume_2 
       |                      |                    
       |   0.64 s  consume_1  |  0.65 s  consume_1 
       |   0.80 s  consume_2  |  0.68 s  consume_2 
       |                      |                    
       |   0.64 s  consume_1  |  0.64 s  consume_1 
       |   0.78 s  consume_2  |  0.68 s  consume_2 
-------+----------------------+-------------------
Debug  |   real   0m 4.327s   |  real   0m 3.987s
       |   user   0m 3.987s   |  user   0m 3.902s
       |   sys    0m 0.340s   |  sys    0m 0.084s
```

The "Debug" came from calling it as `time python test.py`. For "without", `sys` is consistently around 0.32 seconds. For "with" it's consistently around 0.09 seconds.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243357/discussion-on-question-by-pychopath-20-faster-with-unused-variable-why).